# TargetException thrown in Reflection using GetValue() in nested properties

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I need to get the *Name* and *Value* of all properties of each object. Some of them are reference type so if I get the following objects:

```
public class Artist {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Album {
    public string AlbumId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Artist AlbumArtist { get; set; }
}
```

When getting the properties from the `Album` object I would need also to get the values of properties `AlbumArtist.Id` and `AlbumArtist.Name` which are nested.

I have the following code so far, but it triggers the **System.Reflection.TargetException** when trying to get the value of the nested ones.

```
var valueNames = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var property in row.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (property.PropertyType.Namespace.Contains("ARS.Box"))
    {
        foreach (var subProperty in property.PropertyType.GetProperties())
        {
            if(subProperty.GetValue(property, null) != null)
                valueNames.Add(subProperty.Name, subProperty.GetValue(property, null).ToString());
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        var value = property.GetValue(row, null);
        valueNames.Add(property.Name, value == null ? "" : value.ToString());
    }
}
```

So in the `If` statement I just check if the property is under the namespace of my reference types, if it is I should get all the nested properties values but that's where the exception is raised.

Comment: Why do you need reflection if you have `Album` object?

Comment: Well I should receive a whole lot more different objects which I can only know at runtime.

Comment: Using dictionary for this approach(flat list of property names and values) would fail it two classes had the same property like `Name`

Comment: You're right, I didn't include the part of the code where I check if the value already exist, cause even though more than one row of data could come in, I only need it once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This fails because you are trying to get an `Artist` property on a `PropertyInfo` instance:

```
if(subProperty.GetValue(property, null) != null)
    valueNames.Add(subProperty.Name, subProperty.GetValue(property, null).ToString());
```

As I understand you need the values from the `Artist` instance which is nested inside the `row` object (which is an `Album` instance).

So you should change this:

```
if(subProperty.GetValue(property, null) != null)
    valueNames.Add(subProperty.Name, subProperty.GetValue(property, null).ToString());
```

to this:

```
var propValue = property.GetValue(row, null);
if(subProperty.GetValue(propValue, null) != null)
    valueNames.Add(subProperty.Name, subProperty.GetValue(propValue, null).ToString());
```

Full (with a little change to avoid calling GetValue when we don't need)

```
var valueNames = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var property in row.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (property.PropertyType.Namespace.Contains("ATG.Agilent.Entities"))
    {
        var propValue = property.GetValue(row, null);
        foreach (var subProperty in property.PropertyType.GetProperties())
        {
            if(subProperty.GetValue(propValue, null) != null)
                valueNames.Add(subProperty.Name, subProperty.GetValue(propValue, null).ToString());
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        var value = property.GetValue(row, null);
        valueNames.Add(property.Name, value == null ? "" : value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Also, you may run into situations when the property names are duplicated, so your `IDictionary<,>.Add` will fail. I suggest to use something more reliable naming here.

For example: `property.Name + "." + subProperty.Name`

Comment: Peter thanks a lot for the quick response. You've been both accurate and concise you've really saved me a lot of time and effort. ^_^